# Learning Recursion, error when calling class

Tags: java

```
public class recursion  {

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        thisclass(0);
    }

    public static void thisclass(int z)
    {
        int x = 1;
        int y = 3;
        if (z==10)
        {
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(x/y);
            x++;
            y= y+2;
            thisclass(z++);
        }
    }

}
```

I'm learning recursion right now and when I get to the else statement in the `thisclass` method, I get an error after it prints an abnormal amount of zeros.

What I want the program to do is run 10 times and do something along the lines of Print 1/3 2/5 3/7 etc.

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: Just FYI, 'thisclass' is a method, not a class and it is extremely confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are as far as I can tell (other than naming conventions) three things that are causing your program to not run as intended.

(1) You are doing integer division in your print, so 1/3 will be 0 (no decimals in ints).

Solution: Change `int x` and `int y` to `double x` and `double y`.

(2) You are post incrementing z when you pass it into the recursive call, meaning the recursive call does not see the new value, but rather the old one.

Solution: Pre-increment z `thisclass(++z)`.

(3) You also likely mean to have `x` and `y` declared outside of your method, so that their updated values persist. (Instead you would just be printing the same value 10 times).

Solution:

```
double x = 1.0;
double y = 3.0;
public static void thisclass(int z){ ...
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the responses, feels like a facepalm moment I should know these things.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
thisclass(z++);
```

Doesn't do what you think it does. It increments 'z' and then calls thisclass on the original value of z. It's a lot like doing:

```
int temp = z;
z = z + 1;
thisclass(temp);
```

You want to use preincrement instead of postincrement here:

```
thisclass(++z);
```

The answers that drunkenRabbit and Serdalis have posted are also valid. It won't work correctly until you've made all of these changes.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting all those `0`'s because you are doing `integer division`, which does not support `1/3` etc.

You should change your code to use `float`'s which will get rid of the `0` problem.

E.g.

```
float x = 1.0;
float y = 3.0;
```

You are also resetting the value of `y` with each call, so `y` will always be `3` at the beginning of the call and `5` at the end. You should check the value of `z` to see what the value of `y` should be.

Same can be said about the value of `x`.

The `z` is being [`post-incremented`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators) at each call, which will cause the value of `z` to not increase with each call, you should change the call to:

```
thisclass(++z);
```

To make tha value [`pre-incremented`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators). Otherwise this call will go on forever.

Also, please don't call your methods `thisclass` is it very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Incrementing x and y in the else condition does not affect the recursive call variable. Think of recursion as a new call to the same method. 
So, when making the recursive call x and y are initialized back to 1 and 3. You can pass x and y as a parameter so the updated value can be passed to each recursive call. Is one way to go about this...

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Hydryh - 
Or make `x` and `y` class variables

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

- it's better to use an initial call function that calls the recursive function itself, for initialization
- use `static` data, otherwise they won't be preserved through the recursive calls
- `recur(z++)` will execute like `recur(z)` resulting in an infinite recurrence, use `recur(z+1)` instead

Code:

```
public class recursion
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        startRecursive(0);
    }

    // using static data
    private static int x = 1, y = 3;

    // initial call
    public static void startRecursive (int initZ)
    {
        x = 1;
        y = 3;

        // avoid infinite recurrence
        if (initZ > 10) initZ = 0;

        recur(initZ);
    }

    // recursive function
    public static void recur(int z)
    {
        if (z == 10)
        {
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(x/y);

            x += 1;
            y += 2;

            recur(z+1); // z++ will return z
        }
    }
}
```